# PHP Post variable loses encoding when posting to database

Tags: php, post, encode

Im sending data with android and i have a variable that have a leter "ž". when php post this into database it becomes a "?". Its not android problem bus android is sending normal value, database is utf_8 so the problem is when parsing to php.

CODE:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
require_once('DB_connect.php');
$db = new DB_connect();
$var=0;

$str = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\u([0-9a-fA-F]{4})/', function ($match) {
    return mb_convert_encoding(pack('H*', $match[1]), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16BE');
}, $str);


$con= new mysqli ("localhost","infoizla_boris","internet1","infoizla_boris");


$place=$_POST['place'];
$name=$_POST['name'];
$number=$_POST['number'];

echo $name;


    $statement=mysqli_prepare($con,"insert into Ocjena (user,place,ocjena) values (?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement,"sss",$name,$place,$number);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
mysqli_stmt_close($statement); 

   if(!mysqli_stmt_execute($statement)){


    $sql="update Ocjena set ocjena='$number' where user='$name' && place='$place'";

   $rez=$con->query($sql);

   }


mysqli_close($con);


?>
```

Comment: You are open to SQL injections. What does `require_once('DB_connect.php');` do, I'd think the connection would be established in there..

Answer (score 0):

you have to tell the connection to [use utf-8](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php) as well

```
$con= new mysqli ("localhost","infoizla_boris","internet1","infoizla_boris");
$con->set_charset("UTF-8");
```